# XML serialization to return an array of String

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, soap, webforms

My current XML response is as shown below(only important parts are shown).I have added service reference which have generated some proxy classes for me which unfortunately are not returning the output as needed.The c# code below only return the last "values" data. What i eventually want is to have arrays of "values" that i will display in a gridview.

```xml
<return>
<fields></fields>
<fields></fields>
<fields></fields>
<values> 
   <value></value>
   <value></value>
   <value></value>
</values>
<values> 
   <value></value>
   <value></value>
   <value></value>
</values>
```

```cs
//proxy class 
 /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.3056.0")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://ws.server.mhaccess.crimsonlogic.com/")]

    public partial class qwsOutput : baseWebServiceOutput {

        private string[] fieldsField;


        public List<string> values { get; set; }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("fields", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true, Order=0)]
        public string[] fields {
            get {
                return this.fieldsField;
            }
            set {
                this.fieldsField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("fields");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable = true, Order = 1)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("value", typeof(string[]), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]

        public List<string> value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.values;
            }
            set
            {
                this.values = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("values");
            }
        }


    }

//code use to call soap request
SoapService.queryWebServiceSoapPortClient client = new 
SoapService.queryWebServiceSoapPortClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userID;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = Password;

SoapService.qwsInput query1 = new SoapService.qwsInput();
SoapService.queryResponse response = new 
SoapService.queryResponse();

query1.userId = userID;
query1.pass = Password;
query1.queryId = queryId;
query1.qwsInputParams = InputParam;

query a = new query();

a.queryInput = query1;

try
{
    response = client.query(a);
}
catch (Exception error)
{

    var b = error.ToString();
}
```

//updated code

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.3056.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://ws.server.mhaccess.crimsonlogic.com/")]
public partial class qwsOutput : baseWebServiceOutput {

    private string[] fieldsField;

    //private string[][] valuesField;

    private object[] valuesField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("fields", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true, Order=0)]
    public string[] fields {
        get {
            return this.fieldsField;
        }
        set {
            this.fieldsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("fields");
        }
    }

    ///// <remarks/>
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=true, Order=1)]
    //[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("values", typeof(returnValues), Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("values", typeof(returnValues), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 1)]

    public object[] values {
        get {
            return this.valuesField;
        }
        set {
            this.valuesField = value;
            //this.RaisePropertyChanged("values");
        }
    }
}






/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class returnValues
{

    private returnValuesValue[] valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("value", Form = 
    System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public returnValuesValue[] value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}



/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class returnValuesValue
{

}
```

Comment: Seems like you want a list/ array of arrays, as you have multiple `values`-tags in your xml. The you surely also need a nested structure of that data in your class as well, e.g. a `string[mySize][]`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere exactly can you show me some code.

Comment: You need to two attributes above the class values :   [XmlArray("values")]
    [XmlArrayItem("value")]

Comment: @jdweng can you show me an example.

Comment: You have two attributes above the value class.  Replace with the two I posted.

Comment: @jdweng as mentioned i tried this but the return value is 0.

  [XmlArray("values" ,Order=1)]
        [XmlArrayItem("value")]
        public List<string[]> values {
            get
            {
                return this.valuesField;
            }
            set {
                this.valuesField=value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("values");
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

I tested following code and it works :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication110
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Return));
            Return _return = (Return)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("return")]
    public class Return
    {
        [XmlElement("fields")]
        public List<string> fields { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("values")]
        public List<Value> values { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("value")]
    public class Value
    {
        [XmlElement("value")]
        public List<string> value { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: i have added the complete class in the updated question. i can't figure out how to modify the latter as per your example. The code above have been generated as part of the proxy class when i have added the soap service as service reference.can you have a look directly at this please.

Comment: Since you are getting a response which is a string I modified code to work with a string.  For testing, I took the data from a file which you do not need to do.

Comment: i have updated the question with the code am using. i am getting count =0 for the return values

Comment: Comment out your attributes and add mine.  Then remove comments one at a time so you learn what is causing the issues.

Comment: still couldn't figure out what is not working. can you modify my code directly please.

Comment: There are too many differences between your code and mine.  Are you deserializing  the RETURN class like in my code.

Comment: I actually figure out how to get the number of "values" . But now i can't get any value,its showing me count=0. see updated question

Comment: You still aren't using my classes.

Comment: i actually did comment out my code and use yours but am getting fields and value count=0. with my current code it is actually returning me the numbers of "values" but the value count is still zero

Comment: Are you using same xml that was posted?  My code worked with posted xml and adding the missing closing tag.

Comment: Got my answer https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d08c72f5-9ce4-44a0-9ded-a470b1cf3dec/xml-serialization-to-return-an-array-of-string?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: My code is a LOT simpler than the link.  What was wrong?